# Having a "B-side"

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

> "Everyone has a B-side, tell us a little bit about yours."

What does B-side mean in this context? I tried searching the web, but could only find record-related results.

Comment: Record related results are what you needed. Look up what A and B sides are. Then ask yourself, if you were a record, your A-side might be the things people already know about you, the parts of your character that anyone can see easily ... but what would your B side be?

Comment: It's just a simple metaphor. You'll also find the same reference in, for example, [Jesse Law ... has a "flip side" to his personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesse_Law). But note that *flip side* has closer associations with *his **dark** side,* and *on the **downside***.

Comment: @Spagirl That was my first thought, but it's not quite the same as Josh's answer.

Comment: It refers to audio "records", especially of the 45 RPM variety, where the main song was on the "A side" and some other, less well known song was on the "B side".  In more than a few cases the "B side" recording became the one that achieved more fame and endured in people's memories.  Thus, "B side" is used as a metaphor for the less-obvious (and occasionally unseemly) part of a story/personality/whatever.  It is not necessarily implying "dark side", but it does not exclude that possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a metaphorical use of the "a-side/b-side" description of [vinyl singles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_(music)) which is being applied to an individual's psychology.

Your "a-side" is the *person* you present to the public as the popular, likeable *you*.  It is the person that attempts to look their best and who makes a conscious effort to be sociable and popular with your friends.

Your "b-side" is the unadorned, uncensored you.  The *secret* you.

So while your a-side is busy telling everyone how much you hate Donald Trump, your b-side is screaming "build the wall".

Comment: This seems to make the most sense with context. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think it refers to the figurative meaning of ***[B-side](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/b-side):*** (also ***flip side***)

> - the less important side of a single (= a record containing one song on each side)

that is:

> - an opposite, reverse, or sharply contrasted side or aspect of something or someone.

Comment: Hi, where is the second quote from, i don't see it in your link?